# Windows Workflow runs very slowlyh on my DEV machine

Tags: workflow-foundation, performance

I am developing an app using WF hosted in IIS as WCF services as a business layer.

This runs quickly on any machine running Windows Server 2008 R2, but very slowly on our dev machines, running Windows XP SP3.

Yesterday, the workflows were as fast on my dev machine as they are on the server for the whole day.

Today, they are back to running slowly again (I rebooted overnight)

Has anyone else experienced this problem with workflows running slowly on IIS in XP? What did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it has now sorted itself out again. It looks like keeping your OS patched is the solution